# Temporarily disable gesture recognizer swiping functionality

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a uiview with multipe buttons and images on it. I drag that card kind of like a tinder interface.

I want to be able stop the user dragging the card at some points and allow them at others.

I tried disabling it but the way I was doing it disabled all user interaction with the whole view stopping the swiping but also stopping users hitting the button which I don't want to do (I only want to stop them swiping).

This is how I initiate the swipe:

```
let gestureBack = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDraggedBack:"))
backview.addGestureRecognizer(gestureBack)
```

This is how I incorrectly attempted to stop the swiping:

```
  self.backview.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

How can I just stop the view from swiping without it affecting all the other buttons ect inside the view.

Thanks

Comment: First try gestureBAck.enabled = NO, if it didn't work, then you need to set a flag in your wasDraggedBAck method, and only proceed if that flag is set YES.

Comment: pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991250/disable-gesture-recognizer

Answer (score 6):

yes for this there is a delegate method's for `UIGestureRecognizer` u can set the delegate method like below

```
let gestureBack = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDraggedBack:"))
backview.addGestureRecognizer(gestureBack)
//set the delegate
 gestureBack.delegate? = self
```

and also confirm to delegate like,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

}
```

and finally use this delegate method to trigger action,

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    //condition to recognise the gesture 
    return true; //or false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the docs, all `UIGestureRecognizer` class objects has a `enabled` property.

What it does is:

> Disables a gesture recognizers so it does not receive touches. The default value is true. If you change this property to false while a gesture recognizer is currently recognizing a gesture, the gesture recognizer transitions to a cancelled state.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like,

```
 gestureBack.enabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You need to disable the gesture.

```
gesture.isEnabled = enabled
```

I have several view objects with gestures registered. The solution I have implemented is as follows.

1. Created a function that will enable/disable gestures on all views in a controller except for the selected view.

```
/// Set other views interaction off except the selected view
/// Prevent the image accidentally taking over
private func setViewGestures(enabled: Bool, excludedView: UIView) {
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if subview == excludedView {
            continue
        }
        // Disable gestures
        if let gestures = subview.gestureRecognizers {
            for gesture in gestures {
                gesture.isEnabled = enabled
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Next, in the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` function:

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    guard let gestureView = gestureRecognizer.view else {
        return false
    }
    setViewGestures(enabled: false, excludedView: gestureView)
}
```

3. Finally, in the gesture recognizer function, when the gesture ends, re-enable the gestures again.

```
@objc func handlePan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let gestureView = gesture.view else {
        return
    }
    if gesture.state == .ended {
        setViewGestures(enabled: true, excludedView: gestureView)
    }
    // Do gesture stuff
}
```

That's it! The gestures are disabled while a single one is active and re-enables the gestures once the gesture ends.